# creating array field in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a collection in mongodb where a field named `lists` will contain an array of `link` and `linkName`. I am successfully able to create a two seperate field `link` and `linkName`, however not able to store the value inside `lists`.

Model code for mongodb :-

```
const socialSchema = new Schema({
    lists: [{
        link:{ formType: String},
        linkName: { formType: String}
    }]
})
```

API code :-(this code is for creating only, will later on try to use `findOneAndUpdate` to update the existing field

```
router.route('/', [auth]).post(async (req, res) => {
    const {linkName, link } = req.body
    try {
        console.log(req.body)//Ex. { linkName: 'facebook', link: 'www.facebook.com'}
        const social = new Social({
          //Stuck here!!!
        })
        await social.save()
        res.json(social)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Errors')
    }
   }
)
```

Part of frontend Code(React)

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        linkName: '',
        link: ''
  });
  const {linkName, link} = formData

  const onChange = e =>
  setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const socialList = {
      linkName,
      link
    }
    try {
      const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };
      const body = JSON.stringify(socialList)
      const res = await Axios.post('/api/social', body, config)
      console.log(res)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: try this  const social = new Social({
          lists : [req.body]
        })

Comment: It did add into `lists` but the `link` and `linkName` were not added inside it.

Comment: What does it display when you add a console.log("red body: ", req.body) in your post route?

Comment: It displays: `{ linkName: 'facebook', link: 'www.facebook.com'}`

Answer (score 0):

In your schema change from `{formType: String}` to `{type: String}`.

```
const data = {link: req.body.link, linkName: req.body.linkName};
Social.create({
  links: [data]
});
```

This should work.

---

**MY FULL WORKING CODE THAT I TESTED**

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  links: [
    {
      link: { type: String },
      linkName: { type: String }
    }
  ]
});

const Model = mongoose.model("test", schema);

const doc = { link: "link", linkName: "linkname" };

Model.create({
    links: [doc]
});
```

---

Comment: It's working now, actually I read somewhere to not to use `type` as it matches the keyword in mongoose and conflicts with the data name and hence changed that thing. Thanx for helping me out still :)